# How to get an element from a Set?

Tags: java, set

I have a `Set<Integer>` in my Java program which is guaranteed to be non-empty. I want to retrieve one of the Integers from this set. I do not care which Integer, I just need some Integer, deterministically or nondeterministically selected from the set, as long as it is in the set. What is the best way to do this?

Comment: Iterate the set until you find an integer, that's it.

Comment: I will get a random number using `Set#size` then navigate through the `Set` using an enhanced `for` loop until reach the random number calculated before and return that element from the `Set`. It is not a good solution but will do.

Comment: what kind (implementation) of Set is it?  HashSet, TreeSet, etc...

Comment: How to define "the best way"?

Comment: I am keeping the implementation of the set flexible by using the Set interface rather than typing my variables with one of the specific implementations but, in practice, this will be a HashSet. I am defining the best way as the most elegant solution.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Why not just take the first element?

```
return set.iterator().next();
```

If it's guaranteed to be non-empty, and you don't care which element you retrieve, this sounds about as simple as it gets.

Comment: Yeah, perfect. I will be accepting your answer as soon as Stack Overflow lets me. This is an elegant solution to my silly problem.

Comment: +1; with regards to the (IMO questionable) requirements, this is the best solution

Comment: @BigEndian while this approach does what you requested, I seriously think you need to explain why is *good* to retrieve an element from the `Set`, and if it should be the same element through several calls, which derives in: why to keep the data in a `Set` to begin with?

Comment: Haha, I have a very good reason for wanting to do this. The set of integers represents equivalent states (integers) in a deterministic finite automaton. I am writing a method to minimize an unoptomized automaton. Near the end of this process I have a Set<Set<Integer>> each Set<Integer> in the Set<Set<Integer>> represents a state in the optimized automaton. I need to grab the state transition information from one of the states in this Set<Integer>, and since the states are equivalent, it doesn't matter which.

Comment: @BigEndian looks like your real problem is the design of your solution and retrieving an element from the `Set<Integer>` is just a hack...

Comment: If you like, you can look at "Basics of Compiler Design" Anniversary Edition by Torben Mogensen available as a pdf online (http://www.diku.dk/~torbenm/Basics/) and go to section 2.8 where it talks about minimization of a DFA. I am curious to know how you would approach this. My DFA class keeps track of a Set<Integer> states and a Map<Character, Integer> transitions. This method should use that information to produce a minimized DFA.

Comment: Sometimes programmers have to use hacks. I considered other approaches, but this one is substantially more simple in all other regards, save for this one hack.

Answer (score 2):

There are a few ways. One is to call [iterator()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Set.html#iterator%28%29).  Then call `next()` on the [Iterator](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Iterator.html).

Alternatively, you can call [toArray](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Set.html#toArray%28T%5B%5D%29) then an element from that array (bound by the size of it).

Comment: why do you want to convert it to array when you can take the first element,

Comment: @SrinivasReddyThatiparthy I'm giving *options*, not the first thing that you happen to think of.

Answer (score 1):

```
private Integer getIntegerFromSet(Set<?> set) {

    Integer integerToReturn = null;

    if (set != null && !set.isEmpty()) {

        for (Object o : set) {

            if (o instanceof Integer) {

                integerToReturn = (Integer) o;
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    return integerToReturn;
}
```

I always check for nullness, even if I'm "guaranteed" that I'm getting a non-empty, instantiated object.  This method will accept any implementation of a `Set`, iterate through it, and check for the first occurrence of any object that is an Integer.

Comment: A very robust solution, but this is overkill for my purposes! This answer may be useful for others with different needs than me, so I will upvote.

Comment: Yea, before I posted, I hadn't noticed the Set you were acting on was strongly typed, which is why my solution checks the type of the Set's elements.  But thank you for the upvote, hope you find what you need.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply take the first element?

```
int elem() {
    return set.toArray()[0]; 
}
```